PCIe 4 and 5 GT/s characteristic, its connection to frequency
While designing a board that uses PCIe gen5 interface, I was wondering how exactly gen5 standart achieves double data speed comparing to gen4 (32GT/s PCIe5 and 16GT/s PCIe4)? Both 4 and 5 are 16ghz signals that use NRZ modulation.
In search for some info I stumbled on a Robert Feranic's video "Understanding High Speed Signals - PCIE, Ethernet, MIPI"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeMUGSKyeRE
and the moment he asks about 32 GT/s - 16GHz dependency, it was said that you just divide 32 by 2 and thats that, which is hardly an explanation sinse all previous gens have equal GT/s and GHz numbers.
Also, I found an aplication note by TI "High-Speed PCB Layout for PCIe Gen 5" (snla426), in which it is said that after Link Equalization the Minimum Eye Width for PCIe5 is 9.375 ± 0.5ps, while for PCIe4 it is 18.75 ± 0.55ps.
Could this be the reason the raw data speed is twice as faster in gen5 comparing to gen4?
Addition to the question:
If, as said in comments, the actual frequency of PCIe4 is 8Ghz, why is it that in many sources it is said to be 16Ghz? Like this, for example
https://www.tomshardware.com/news/what-we-know-about-pcie4,39063.html
https://www.rambus.com/blogs/pci-express-4/

The relationship is the same - PCIe Gen 4 was 16GT/s or 8GHz (not 16GHz). Gen 5 is 32GT/s or 16GHz. Why? If you send a bitstream of 010101010 at 32Gbps, it is equivalent to sending a 16GHz clock signal.

Although your comment puts clarity to my poor understanding of the topic, I, unfortunately, can not understand, why in so many cases the maximum frequency of, for example, PCIe4, is said to be 16GHz with 16GT/s. Also, in question you are refering to you mention 8Gbt/s that gives fundamental 4GHz. If I understand it correctly, the actual bits per second rate depends from encoding type, and cannot be assosiated to GT/s like one to one, especially for gen 1 and 2.

Can I ask you to translate the same example to PCIe2? The encoding for gen to is 8b/10b, and 5 GT/s is not exactly 5Gbps

Realistically frequency is meaningless - the actually bandwidth required to send the signal is about 5-7 times higher than the fundamental! Which is why all the official stuff talks in bit rates. PCIe uses GT/s to indicate it is talking at the link rate. In references where they us Gbps they are talking about the data rate without encoding (so 4Gbps for Gen 2, ~7.8Gbps for Gen3). Anyone using 16GHz when referring to PCIe 4 is simply interchaging units incorrectly - that article is the first time I've seen it used.

PCIe 2 will be 2.5GHz - half of of the link/transfer rate. It is actually exactly 5Gbps link transfer rate (a.k.a GT/s). The fundamental frequency doesn't depend on the encoding, just the link rate, as the encoding happens before transmitting.
